# Factorization of an integer and then taking the factorial of each element

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, factorial

Let $N$ be an integer such that $N=a_n\cdot a_{n-1}\cdots a_0$ is a decomposition into $n+1$ arbitrary integers.

Is there a rule to get the biggest possible number, when taking the factorials of each element of the decomposition and multiplying them together?

$$a_n!\cdot a_{n-1}!\cdots a_0!$$

By rule I mean can we find the best amount of elements for a decomposition like $n=2$ or $n=4$. And also how should those elements be chosen? More equally distributed?

So for example we have $N=100$ and compare a decomposition of $n=3$ with $n=2$. Let's chose $$2\cdot 5 \cdot 10=10\cdot10=100$$

Then we clearly have
$$870912000=2!\cdot 5!\cdot 10! \leq 10!\cdot 10! = 13168189440000 $$

So the decomposition $10\cdot 10$ gives a bigger result. But is it the biggest?

EDIT: So the answer will be $n=1$. What about if we have to chose $n\geq 2$? So atleast we have a decomposition of $2$ elements?

Comment: Well, for $2$ elements, you can take $2!\cdot(N/2)!$.

Comment: @barakmanos Why do you assume that $N$ is even? Let $N=p$ be an odd prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Sorry, I meant, take $p$ the smallest factor of $N$, and use $p!\cdot(N/p)!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any pair of positive numbers $a$ and $b$ we have
$$a!b!=\prod_{i=1}^ai\prod_{j=1}^bj<\prod_{i=1}^ai\prod_{j=1}^b(a+j)=(a+b)!,$$
so in particular if $a>1$ and $b>1$ (so that $a+b\leq ab$) it follows that $a!b!<(ab)!$. Of course if either $a=1$ or $b=1$ then we have $a!b!=(ab)!$. This means that the maximum is always attained with the smallest number of factors.

As for the edited question; if multiple factors are required then you'll need to allow trivial factors, otherwise the question makes no sense for primes if $n\geq2$. The argument above shows that the maximum is then attained for the trivial decomposition $N=N\times1\times1\ldots\times1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there also a rule on how to chose the integers? I assume one should chose the biggest and smallest integer and not integers that have around the same value.

Comment: Choose which integers?

Comment: I mean if we chose a decomposition of two of the number $100$ Then clearly $$10!\cdot 10!<50!\cdot 2!<1!\cdot 100!$$
So the bigger the number, the higher the result?

Comment: Yes, it follows from the argument above, because
$$a!b!\leq(ab)!=1!\cdot(ab)!.$$
It's what my second paragraph says in a very rough manner.

Answer (score 0):

The largest will be $N!$ itself. Indeed, consider binomial/multinomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

No, $100=1\cdot 100$ is the biggest, with $1!\cdot 100!=  9.3326215443944152681699238856266700491$ E157

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And if we chose at least $n \geq 2$? Is it safe to say the biggest result one will get with the smallest amount of elements?

Comment: Unfortunately $n\ge 2$ is not possible for prime numbers $N$ in a nontrivial way.

Comment: So I can get a larger number for example $$a_n ! \cdots a_0! \geq  b_1 !  \cdot b_0!$$ for $a_n\cdots a_0=b_1\cdot b_0$?

Comment: Yes, try $N=17$. Then $1!17!\ge 17!$. But strictly bigger, no.

Comment: I don't understand, if strictly bigger is not possible then it is safe to say the biggest result one will get with the smallest amount of elements? Meaning the following inequality should always hold:
$$a_n!\cdots a_0! \leq b_{n-1}!\cdots b_{0}!$$
under the assumption $a_n\cdots a_0 = b_{n-1}\cdots b_0$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You should write $<$ instead of $\le$. then everything is clear. Otherwise $1!a!\ge a!$ is true, although we have more factors.

Comment: Notic that if $N$ is a prime, then $N$'s only factorization is $1\cdot1\cdot\ldots\cdot1\cdot N$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I said this already above.